# I want to compare a time value to the datetime value

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I want to filter my results with respect to date and time....I have date stored in a separate field which is of datetime data type...Another field stores Time value but as it is a datetime data type so it stores current system date along with the entered time. Now when I filter results using date then it runs well and shows the results between specific period like between dates from 12/10/2011 and 12/15/2011...But when I want to show results with respect to time it doesn't show any results...

I am using dataadapter and dataset for retrieving records from the sql server database... Please tell me the solution for comparing time value taken from the textbox with the datetime value stored in the database so that i get results between specific time like between 12:00 pm and 6:00 pm

More Clear:

Actually I have datetime value stored in the database. What I am taking from the textbox is a time value. I want to extract those results from the database which are between the given time value....To be more concise, my application is a booking system for a sports club and provides an option to view alreaady made bookings.. Here i offer two options either to view all bookings for a specific game or to filter bookings. In filter bookings one option is to filter through date and time...Date option is running okay but problem lies in time part...I provide two times but unable to view bookings between them...

My code is:

```
        Dim prmtimefrom As New SqlParameter("@booking_time", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        prmtimefrom.Value = TextBox3.Text

        Dim prmtimeto As New SqlParameter("@booking_tim", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        prmtimeto.Value = TextBox4.Text




        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bookings where booking_time Between @booking_time AND @booking_tim AND game = " & x, con)   ' x is the name of a specific game

        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(prmtimefrom)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(prmtimeto)
        da.Fill(ds, "Bookings")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to do this in vb.net, or how to do this in SQL from the database.  In order to filter in .NET, you need to use the [DateTime.TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) property.  A simple example would be:

```
'Set the from time to start Jan 1, 2011 at 8:00am
Dim startTime as DateTime = New DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0)

'Set the to time to end Feb 3, 2006 at 1:30pm
Dim endTime as DateTime = New DateTime(2006, 2, 3, 13, 30, 0)

'Compare the current time to the start / end times
'Notice that the dates are ignored, we are only comparing times
If Now.TimeOfDay >= startTime.TimeOfDay AndAlso Now.TimeOfDay <= endTime.TimeOfDay Then
    MsgBox("Within time span")
Else
    MsgBox("Outside of time span")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim starting = TimeSpan.Parse("12:00")
Dim ending = TimeSpan.Parse("18:00")

Dim query = _
    From dr in dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)() _
    Let tod = dr.Field(Of DateTime)(0).TimeOfDay _
    Where tod >= starting AndAlso tod < ending _
    Select dr
```